# Error When installing vim

Tags: 12.04

I was trying to install vim using command `sudo apt-get install vim` then it is showing error as Package `vim` has no installation candidate.What is problem ?

Comment: Try doing apt-get update and then try installing again

Comment: How much internet data will it take ??

Comment: Than you very much..solved

Comment: @Fabby Already have that done :) I suppose I could delete the comment I originally posted, right ?

Comment: @Nikhil: As you're a reputation 1 user: please, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of the answer below, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)
So that other users like you, will find a valid answer!

Answer (score 0):

Do `sudo apt-get update` and then  install again

Comment: Good point hehe.   Just side effect of my copy - pasting addiction :)